# Yii Framework in Netbeans - Object Method Autocomplete Not Appearing

Tags: php, netbeans, yii, autocomplete

I have just noticed that the object method autocomplete does not bring up a list of methods to autocomplete with. I saw it when I was using the $PDO->bindParam() method. Normally, I can just start typing "bi" after the method arrow and the autocomplete will come straight up with the method. Now, these methods do not appear, however methods and attributes in my personally defined classes will appear. Also, it says "PHPDoc not found".

It's strange because it has worked fine previously. The only thing I can think of is that I had to delete the project out of Netbeans and then recover it back using "new project from existing sources".

Is there a broken link to a documentation file I need to re-connect? How would I go about fixing this? Also, apologies if this is an asinine question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Code completion

To get context sensitive code completion, follow these steps:

```
Include Yii folder (assuming it is properly placed outside project directory)
    Open "File > Project properties > PHP Include Path" and add the Yii framework root path
Ignore yiilite.php to avoid doubled/missing documentation
    Open "Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Files"
    Add to the front of "Files Ignored by the IDE" the file "^(yiilite\.php|CVS|SCCS|...."
    Restart NetBeans
Code completion in view files
    Add the following PHPDoc statement at the head of the file to use code completion in view files. (you may add additional passed parameters as well)

/* @var $this PostController */
/* @var $model Post */
$this->getSomeProValue(); // possible with code completion
$model->author; // possible with code completion
```

Usage:

```
Typing suggestions: Ctrl-Space
Show Function parameters: Ctrl-P
Comment your own code with PHPDoc style. Here's a good example.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And thanks especially for the ignoring YiiLite part. It's been bugging me for ages.